# How to call an Activity from service class

Tags: android, service

```
public class FinishService extends Service{

 private NotificationManager mNM;
 public static String ChangeDate;
 public static Context mContext;
 public static String today;



 private int NOTIFICATION = R.string.local_service_started;
 private int START_STICKY;


 public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
     FinishService getService() {
            return FinishService.this;
        }
    }




 @Override
public void onCreate() {
     mContext=FinishService.this;
      mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         showNotification();
}



  @SuppressLint("Override")
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
            // stopped, so return sticky.
            return START_STICKY;
        }



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}

//@Override
public void onDestroy() {

            if(AstrobixStaticMethod.isInternetAvailable(FinishService.this)){
                 Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 
                 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                 ChangeDate=formatter.format(date);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            try{
                cal.setTime(sdf.parse(ChangeDate));
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            ChangeDate=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+ChangeDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Next Date", ChangeDate);
            RahuActivity.nextAlaram();  

            }
            else{
                Intent mIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Information.class);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(mIntent);


            }


}



private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void showNotification() {
        // This is the 'title' of the notification
        CharSequence title = "Rahukaal has finished.!!";
        // This is the icon to use on the notification
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        // This is the scrolling text of the notification
        //CharSequence text =RahuParserClasses.mList.get(0);
        CharSequence text ="Rahukaal Time Finished Now";
        // What time to show on the notification
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    //  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, RahuTimeActivity.class), 0);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
        // Clear the notification when it is pressed
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        //Vibrates fon on notification
        notification.vibrate=new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500 };
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        //Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        // Send the notification to the system.

        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);


        stopSelf();

    }
```

Can anyone help me.i make an application where i set the alarm from matching time.
when time is matching service class is running but i have coded on destroy method 
if internet is not available on phone.it will go to BroadcastReceiver class but it
is gone and shows an error when application not open.

Loacat error here:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service   com.astrobix.service.FinishService@40523370: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:    Unable to find explicit activity class { com.astrobix.astrobixrahukaal/com.astrobix.service.Information}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: Actually what you want to achieve? - If internet is not available you want to run the Broadcast Receiver? is that you want? Actually your question is a little bit confusing. :(

Comment: astrobixrahukaal - is this your actvity name?

Comment: @ Jashan:-ya its my project name not activity name where i declare the pending intent that activity name is RahuActivity..

Comment: Information.class ? what kind of class is that activity/service/broadcastreceiver? my doubt is Information.class is not an activity, which you are calling using startActivity method.

Comment: @ Jashan:- Its my BroadcastReceiver class

Comment: try with this method sendBroadcast(mIntent). This will call your broadcast receiver.

Comment: @Jashan:-Please vote me otherwise my id is blocked please help me

Comment: no one is downvoted your thread then why should stackoverflow block you? Did you got ur program working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you can't use **startActivity** method on a broadcast receiver try with this one.

```
`Intent mIntent=new Intent(FinishService.this,Information.class);
```

sendBroadcast(mIntent);`

Comment: Oh God !!. so you are posting a question to build a profile? It's sad and very unprofessional. Never ask a vote in SO. okey. already I have voted for your question. I can't vote for the comments. :( Coz in your comments there is nothing useful for the community. Do one thing you can post your own answer, I will vote it for you.

Comment: @ Jashan-this is my question which i posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991116/how-to-call-an-activity-from-service-class?noredirect=1#comment26306314_17991116 thanks a frnd i needed of because stackflow blocked my last id's it i have not 20 above reputation that's why

Answer (score 1):

Error explains your issue

> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Add your Activity to AndroidManifest inside Application tag:

```
<activity android:name=".newActivity">
```

Comment: -but from where i call the class this is my serive class and where i send through intent that is BroadcastReceiver class and both class i have mentioned in Manifest.xml file

Comment: @FarhaSameer786 Are you sure this activity is in correct package? Post whole logcat message.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(mContext,Information.class);
            mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
```

Unable to find explicit activity class {com.astrobix.astrobixrahukaal/com.astrobix.service.Information}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
have u added in the AndroidManifest?
```

Comment: -mContext is refered to which class...ya i have added both service class and broadcastreceiver in Manifest file

Comment: the one which u have created in onCreate()